# MongoDB: dropping indexes on a secondary in a replica set

Tags: mongodb

I dropped an index on a primary in a replica set today (1 primary, 1 secondary) and it almost caused an outage for my service. The read/write ticket count dropped to 0 for a few seconds and the latency for all queries was awful!

I need to drop more indexes tomorrow but can't reply on executing db.collection.dropIndex() for the above reason.

I was thinking of a different approach and wondering if this is a good idea or not? Thoughts?

1. Drop the indexes on the secondary,
2. Preform a failover of the primary,
3. Drop the indexes on the new secondary

I'm using Mongo: 3.2 (wiretiger)

Comment: The procedure I outlined above is actually the recommended way to build indexes in a replica set: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/build-indexes-on-replica-sets/

Comment: To be clear, are you planning on dropping indexes from the Secondary node by bringing it up in a stand-alone state? Dropping an index is technically a write operation; writes are only allowed on a Primary. Dropping an index should generally be an immediate operation. Was your database impacted because indexes were still needed by some query patterns, or for some other reason?

Comment: Yes to your first question. Database was not impacted because the index was needed, the dropIndex command took about 5 seconds to execute and return control to the CLI. DB was impacted during this period and for a few minutes afterwards. After about 10 minutes all graphs (tickets, latency, etc) returned to normal. I verified that this was not a coincidence by retrying this experiment 30 minutes later and got the same results!

Comment: According to this: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/command/dropIndexes/#dbcmd.dropIndexes dropIndex obtains a write lock on the database until its completed!